# Reverse Markov type inequalities

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose $X$ is a discrete nonnegative random variable, and we wish to show $\Pr(X<a)>0$ for some $a<\mathbb{E}(X)$.  Are there any results (possibly depending on the variance and other statistics) which might help us?

Answer (score 1):

If $EX=\mu$, then either $X=\mu$ almost surely or $P(X<\mu)>0$ (why?). In the former case you are obviously doomed to fail. In the latter, since $X$ is discrete there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $P(\mu-\varepsilon<X<\mu)=0$.  Your inequality now holds with $a=\mu-\frac\varepsilon2$.

This deals with existence, but how do we find a candidate for $a$? Choose $p>1$ and set $c_p:=E(X^{1/p})$. By Jensen's inequality, we have $c_p<\mu^{1/p}$, the inequality being strict under the assumption that $X$ is not degenerate. If we put $a:=[\frac12(c_p+\mu^{1/p})]^p$, then

$$P(X\ge a)=P(X^{1/p}\ge a^{1/p})\le a^{-1/p}c_p=\frac{2c_p}{c_p+\mu^{1/p}}<1,$$
so $P(X<a)\ge\frac{\mu^{1/p}-c_p}{c_p+\mu^{1/p}}>0.$

Comment: I think the idea is to estimate this $\varepsilon $ using summary statistics like the variance if possible.

Comment: Fair point. I'll add a little more.